# Changing culture in vb.net causes my double to error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I decided to force culture settings as too stop some formatting problems.

However, now I get errors such as this:

Conversion from string "548568.68" to type 'Double' is not valid

My only change was to add the following:

Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA")
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA")

Before adding this, it has worked perfectly.

Comment: Well yes - presumably that culture doesn't use `.` as a decimal separator. If you know that that's the format that you will be parsing, I suggest you specify the invariant culture in the parsing operation (which you haven't shown).

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that happens. In en-ZA, `.` doesn't mean anything; `,` is decimals,  (space) is groups. `548568.68` makes no sense. If you are expecting `548568.68` to parse to "548568 point 68", then you will need to specify a specific culture (usually the invariant culture) in your call to `Parse` / `Convert` / etc.

You can see the particulars of this in the `.NumberFormat` of the selected `CultureInfo`.